# Concatenate file contents on nested folders

Tags: java, hdfs, traversal

In few words, what would be the equivalent of:

```
cat `ls out/*/results/part-*`
```

In the hadoop file system?

Worth clarifying that I need to do that from a Java program not from the shell.

Is there a better way to express this "queries"?

Answer (score 0):

```
hadoop fs -cat hdfs://nn1.example.com/out/*/results/part-*
```

Comment: I've edited the question. I should have said that I need to do this from java, not from the shell.